# Разархивирование файлов с определенной структурой

Tags: zip

Имеется много *.zip файлов в определенной структуре каталогов, нужно:

- распаковать содержимое наиболее быстрым способом
- распаковать туда же, где лежат сами *.zip архивы

т.е. была структура:

папка  — архив.zip  — архив1.zip

стало:

папка  — архив.zip  — данные.dat  — архив1.zip  — данные1.dat

сейчас наполовину решено следующим методом:

> find . -iname '*.zip' -exec 7za -mmt16 -bb3 x -aou {} -o/mnt/out \;

но у этого способа есть недостаток:

1. не быстро
2. извлеченные данные из архива сохраняются в один общий каталог

Comment: `7z e -r *.zip`

Comment: Структура каталогов такова, что не все файлы хранятся в одной вложенности.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET STARTFOLDER=C:\tmp\test
SET MODULENAME=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
FORFILES /P %STARTFOLDER% /S /M *.zip /C "cmd /c start 0x220x22 0x22%MODULENAME%0x22 e @path"
```